# Imprevia redactor не видит папку (yii2 advanced)?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Контроллер

```
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
        ],
        'image-upload' => [
            'class' => 'vova07\imperavi\actions\UploadAction',
            'url' => '/images/', // Directory URL address, where files are stored.
            'path' => '@webroot/images/' // Or absolute path to directory where files are stored.
        ],
        'images-get' => [
            'class' => 'vova07\imperavi\actions\GetAction',
            'url' => '/images/blog/', // Directory URL address, where files are stored.
            'path' => '@webroot/images/blog/', // Or absolute path to directory where files are stored.
            'type' => '0',
        ],
        'files-get' => [
            'class' => 'vova07\imperavi\actions\GetAction',
            'url' => '/files/blog/', // Directory URL address, where files are stored.
            'path' => '@webroot/files/blog/', // Or absolute path to directory where files are stored.
            'type' => '1',//GetAction::TYPE_FILES,
        ],
        'file-upload' => [
            'class' => 'vova07\imperavi\actions\UploadAction',
            'url' => '/files/blog/', // Directory URL address, where files are stored.
            'path' => '@webroot/files/blog/' // Or absolute path to directory where files are stored.
        ],
    ];
}
```

_from.php

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'description')->widget(Widget::classname(), [
    'settings' => [
        'lang' => 'ru',
        'minHeight' => 300,
        'pastePlainText' => true,
        'buttonSource' => true,
        'plugins' => [
            'clips',
            'fullscreen'
        ],
        'imageUpload' => '/images',
        'imageManagerJson' => Url::to(['/blog/images-get']),
    ]
]);?>
```

Возникает следующая ошибка:

> http://newblog.local/images 404 (Not Found)

Создал папку images в backend, frontend и даже common в надежде что залетит картинку куда-нибудь в одну из трех )

Настройки чпу делал по этому [гайду](http://usite.today/articles/yii2-advanced-chpu-dlya-backend-i-frontend)

Виджет vova07/yii2-imperavi-widget

Comment: приведите проблемный код прямо в вопросе

Answer (score 0):

```
@webroot/images/
```

Подразумевает что вы должны иметь папку `images` в `/frontend/web/`, если у вас запущено `frontend` приложение.

Оставьте только `path` параметры и создайте папки в `web` директориях.